# Как перевести любой файл в текстовый вид и обратно. Python

Tags: python, файлы, unicode

У меня возникла необходимость переводить файлы такие как (zip, png, exe, и т.д.) в txt файл. Это можно сделать в ручную если переименовать файл например test.png в test.txt и при открытии будет текст в acll кодировке после чего можно проделать обратную операцию. И я решил повторить эти действия в python и получился следующий код:

```
os.rename('zip.zip', 'zip.txt')

f = open('zip.txt', encoding='ANSI')


r = open('new.txt', 'w', encoding='ANSI')
r.write(f.read())
r.close()
f.close()
```

Но при переводе txt обратно в zip то выходит ошибка:

> Повреждённый файл или типа того

Можно это исправить или есть другой вариант сохранения файла в текстовом формате?
(Знаю, идея странная)

Comment: Base64 — стандарт кодирования двоичных данных при помощи только 64 символов ASCII.

Comment: @СергейШ вы предлагаете поменять кодировку на base64?